# Null Pointer Exception on SimpleDateFormat parse

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, simpledateformat

I am getting date from the calender and converting its format using

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf1.parse(datevalue);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(date != null) {
        Date d = new Date(date.getTime());
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        return sdf.format(d);
    }

    return "";
```

But I am getting crash on some of devices and for some devices it is working fine.
I don't know why it is happening on some devices only.

I am getting this in Fabric report:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference    
       at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.parse(SimpleDateFormat.java:1044)
       at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:577)
       at com.app.appUtilities.Utilities.convertDateFormat(Utilities.java:34)
```

Please help me out.

Comment: `datevalue` is obviously `null` in certain circumstances.

Comment: You assigned null to date reference on the second line.

Comment: it is initialized in third line as you can see if u have any fair answer then comment

Comment: @paraskochar as Bathsheba said, `dateValue` is null in some circumstances. It's a simple NPE and all you've got to do is make sure it isn't null!

Comment: @Sufain I am getting date in form of mm/dd/yyyy from user and converting this in yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ form how it can be null          public static String convertDateFormat(String datevalue) {
  SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  Date date = null;
  try {
   date = sdf1.parse(datevalue);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if(date != null) {
   Date d = new Date(date.getTime());
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
   return sdf.format(d);
  }

  return "";
 }

Comment: @paraskochar I said, `datevalue` is null, not `data`!

Comment: @paraskochar `datevalue` is a `String`. Check your code. If you're really interested, just check the line 1044 of `SimpleDateFormat.parse()`.

Comment: datevalue is the string variable having  date that I am getting from calender in mm/dd/yyyy format , and this code is working absolutely fine in many android devices

Comment: @paraskochar then update your question with the code where you're setting values to `datevalue`. All places where you're assigning something to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String dateStr = "04/05/2010"; 

    SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

    try {
        dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

    String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newDateStr, 1).show();
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  Date date = null;
  try {
   date = sdf1.parse(datevalue);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if(date != null) {
   Date d = new Date(date.getTime());
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
   return sdf.format(d);
  }

  return "";